# Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing; using caret train function

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, gbm

I am trying to fit a `gbm` model using the `caret` package. I know other people have had the same problem, but all the solutions provided in the comments of those questions have not worked for my error. Here is my reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(gbm)

Clean_winter_diff<-structure(list(Total = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 19L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 
6L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 
2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
23L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 20L, 5L, 2L), Site = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), 
    Night = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.666666667, 0.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.428571429, 0, 0.6315789, 1, 0.666666667, 
    0.25, 1, 0.333333333, 1, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.666666667, 
    0, 0.5, 0.166666667, 0, 0.5, 0.909090909, 1, 0.333333333, 
    1, 0, 0.222222222, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.5, 
    0.375, 0, 0, 0.222222222, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 
    0, 0.2, 0.75, 0, 1, 1, 0.869565217, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.2, 0.5, 
    0.333333333, 0, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 
    0.75, 1, 0.363636364, 0, 1, 1, 0.222222222, 0.5, 0, 0.142857143, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.333333333, 0.25, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.785714286, 0, 0, 0.833333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.2, 0, 1, 0.166666667, 
    1, 0, 0.666666667, 1, 0, 0, 0.285714286, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.666666667, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.857142857, 
    1, 0.5, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0.2, 1, 1, 0.25, 0.8, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0, 0.666666667, 
    0.333333333, 0, 1, 0.6, 1, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
    0.75, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.375, 0.666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0.666666667, 0, 0.333333333, 0.428571429, 0, 0.4, 0.5, 
    1, 0.5, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.666666667, 0.5, 
    1, 0.5, 0, 0.666666667, 0.5, 0.2, 1), Day = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0.75, 1, 0.333333333, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.571428571, 
    1, 0.368421053, 0, 0.333333333, 0.75, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 
    0.8, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.333333333, 1, 0.5, 0.833333333, 1, 
    0.5, 0.090909091, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 1, 0.777777778, 1, 1, 
    0.8, 1, 1, 0.666666667, 1, 0.5, 0.625, 1, 1, 0.777777778, 
    1, 1, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.333333333, 1, 0.8, 0.25, 1, 
    0, 0, 0.130434783, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.5, 0.666666667, 
    1, 1, 0, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.25, 0, 0.636363636, 
    1, 0, 0, 0.777777778, 0.5, 1, 0.857142857, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0.666666667, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.5, 
    0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.214285714, 1, 1, 0.166666667, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 1, 0, 0.833333333, 
    0, 1, 0.333333333, 0, 1, 1, 0.714285714, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.333333333, 0.6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.142857143, 
    0, 0.5, 1, 0.333333333, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.666666667, 
    1, 1, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.75, 0.2, 0.666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.333333333, 
    0.666666667, 1, 0, 0.4, 0, 1, 0.666666667, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 
    0.25, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.625, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.666666667, 
    1, 0.333333333, 1, 0.666666667, 0.571428571, 1, 0.6, 0.5, 
    0, 0.5, 0.666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333, 0.5, 
    0, 0.5, 1, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.8, 0), Distance_forest = c(0.527747223, 
    0.680189568, 0, 0.310562619, 0.328173668, 0.278522078, 0.722954456, 
    0.784333633, 0.633598813, 0.106383899, 0.525329032, 0.246038608, 
    0.575318257, 0, 0.767179738, 0.443355317, 0.876859332, 0.19139315, 
    0, 0.037535778, 0.432922864, 0.131314978, 0, 0, 0.093159023, 
    0.128161967, 0, 0, 0.006470757, 0.30307544, 0, 0.568211372, 
    0.263593171, 0.131057648, 0.168134106, 0.367657292, 0.717686941, 
    0.163080941, 0, 0.202433621, 0.3842, 0, 0, 0.165167085, 0.929924705, 
    2.120840521, 0.484698725, 1.078311772, 0.366644583, 0.340810601, 
    0.298239859, 0.195581001, 0.02421172, 0, 0.464407271, 0.198840768, 
    0.054828399, 0.489438607, 0.295818359, 0.110773002, 0.496209018, 
    0.67346593, 0.214433884, 0.108712722, 0.529136166, 0.639769867, 
    0, 0.396732499, 0.483450073, 0.001882719, 0.248622382, 0.925764277, 
    0.175704519, 0.622952019, 0, 0, 1.142940058, 1.133076471, 
    0.224133662, 1.083342909, 0.745420612, 0.377062959, 0.08050045, 
    0.162178412, 1.361054023, 0.123874613, 0.49008657, 0.638751698, 
    0.167293055, 0.306236508, 0.581962136, 0.269203966, 0.01981849, 
    0.389124993, 0.333741945, 0.089434216, 0, 0.172470454, 0.174222306, 
    0.298973407, 0.139883014, 0.455618893, 0.612636301, 0.372548564, 
    0.35343891, 0.583316416, 0.291550392, 0.530795339, 0.07577014, 
    0.844212848, 0.106972082, 0.992915959, 0.044859616, 0.820739224, 
    0.799670156, 0.316242417, 0.319460412, 0.810118761, 0.500966406, 
    0.377834056, 0.940032033, 0.151399734, 0.28102882, 0.212952188, 
    0.073000622, 0.370545468, 0.872918616, 0, 0.104900131, 0.081847421, 
    0.216958479, 0.008668498, 0.007014128, 0.495791646, 0.02399882, 
    0.297470809, 0.490666846, 0.415433354, 0.301854897, 0.365931213, 
    0.692253337, 0.165305616, 0.640148893, 0.835302988, 0.768199373, 
    0.153852261, 0.134893226, 0.540233724, 0.335663076, 0.102341147, 
    0.195486707, 0.362254712, 0.324739821, 1.697227338, 0.520683209, 
    0.020203443, 0, 0.275300664, 0.259782193, 0.051199078, 0.217527413, 
    0.550995487, 0.656144105, 0.277954065, 0.091362713, 0.769716859, 
    0.817754331, 0.531972108, 0.330715097, 0.795027122, 0.818699405, 
    0.113381995, 0.73975023, 0.342823482, 0.760817657, 0.817530729, 
    0.700152145, 0.88797978, 0.29428625, 0.108928974, 0.074075782, 
    0.747234676, 0, 0.543069, 0.262442933, 0.262835131, 0.356383731, 
    0.371421971, 0.015478187, 0.601986047, 0, 0.048889129, 0.406113218, 
    0.127855407, 0.396601367, 0.294174095, 1.112770231, 0.066093385, 
    0.833489821, 0.27603216, 0.261494516, 0.139170942, 0.36716509, 
    0.303017066, 0.245362186, 0, 0.071559882, 0.08333732, 0.617973146, 
    0.075376835, 0.778806939, 0, 0.484474765, 0.09264197, 0.605744884, 
    0.568592372, 0.464302103, 0.219293483, 0.115301111, 0.636074027, 
    0.69132069, 0.448515825, 0.150593216, 0, 0.668861867, 0.664099955, 
    0.386919408, 0.568691441, 0.328245416, 0.441309029, 0.216574999, 
    0.191497106, 0.372996079, 0.211736755), Altitude_diff = c(-0.093344147, 
    -0.032953796, -0.166307236, -0.082168137, -0.074024556, 0.011625801, 
    -0.035469849, 0.023688222, -0.035174545, 0.009125112, -0.148026001, 
    -0.136813009, -0.140504929, -0.155278686, -0.141057312, -0.154625722, 
    -0.138962751, 0.021278778, -0.112632, -0.121742996, -0.104769694, 
    -0.062242187, -0.105238068, -0.118123369, -0.116926834, -0.057471783, 
    -0.099749664, -0.138632839, -0.086083588, -0.086340958, -0.109178192, 
    -0.09964916, -0.086616302, -0.113422317, -0.145193425, -0.139987988, 
    -0.12330925, -0.062, -0.073519485, -0.0852851, -0.087, -0.041133632, 
    -0.02300371, 0.145411285, 0.007278729, 0.043087274, 0.12858374, 
    0.074364258, 0.444998927, -0.018522705, -0.028386627, 0.007190659, 
    -0.045301581, -0.057804062, 0.132843404, 0.021017105, -0.078413605, 
    -0.046420864, 0.058002304, -0.081611237, 0.079912634, -0.050522034, 
    -0.024949936, -0.084849548, -0.062893188, -0.041188028, -0.051312736, 
    -0.01290921, -0.072736145, -0.079543025, -0.016072741, -0.019319687, 
    -0.0213343, 0.020119728, -0.071389999, -0.088737882, 0.073720496, 
    -0.019645096, -0.059846527, 0.08921346, -0.027587019, -0.064136113, 
    -0.06246801, -0.049053955, 0.119930542, 0.013316631, -0.060812866, 
    -0.010882792, -0.072900299, -0.00263418, 0.055887116, -0.057, 
    -0.152, -0.082, -0.134, -0.157, -0.117, -0.128, 0.022, -0.129, 
    0.121, 0.126, 0.091, -0.075, 0.014, -0.071, 0.009, -0.137, 
    -0.13, -0.131, -0.054, -0.132, -0.093, -0.134, -0.143, -0.127, 
    -0.089, -0.058, -0.057, -0.057, -0.055, -0.15, -0.17, -0.106, 
    -0.177, -0.009, 0.008, -0.08, 0.067, -0.131, -0.029, -0.016, 
    0.048, -0.154, -0.133, -0.109, -0.056, 0.029, -0.091, 0.031, 
    0.032, 0.022, 0.029, 0.06, 0.075, -0.099, 0.075, 0.202, -0.022, 
    0.013, 0.118, -0.022, -0.034, 0.224, -0.003, 0.095, 0.03, 
    0.04, 0.105, -0.013, 0.031, -0.038, -0.043, -0.01, 0.046, 
    -0.096, -0.028, -0.033, -0.023, 0.066, 0.063, -0.041, -0.001, 
    -0.005, -0.025, 0.047, -0.025, -0.028, -0.002, 0.065, -0.019, 
    -0.133, -0.045, 0.0479274, -0.0969804, -0.0511209, -0.1380578, 
    -0.0619915, -0.1375449, 0.028642, -0.139097, -0.0267313, 
    -0.0866448, -0.0664405, -0.0098812, 0.0950015, -0.0905839, 
    -0.1271573, -0.1345035, 0.0696888, 0.1161573, -0.001593, 
    -0.139097, -0.139097, -0.0351609, -0.1168084, -0.0487204, 
    -0.0427109, 0.0139613, -0.0361378, -0.073785, -0.0521353, 
    0.0207491, -0.0398732, -0.0512241, -0.0480128, -0.0133375, 
    -0.0047241, 0.0556789, -0.0389344, -0.0307192, -0.0410356, 
    -0.0436031, -0.0513303, 0.0914526, 0.108031, 0.078924, -0.0482411, 
    -0.0010576, -0.0543727, 0.1055158, -0.0347792, 0.0091985, 
    -0.0066721), Revisits = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 3, 1, 
    1, 3, 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 7, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 0, 
    0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1), Ratio = c(0, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 7, 0, 4.75, 0, 
    3, 2, 1.5, 9, 0, 2.5, 2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2.2, 
    2, 3, 3, 2.333333333, 3, 0, 2.5, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8, 5, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 1.428571429, 1.333333333, 
    2, 4, 2, 3.285714286, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1.714285714, 5, 0, 6, 3, 
    4.5, 1.555555556, 4, 2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3.666666667, 
    4, 2, 1.5, 4.5, 0, 0, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 4, 
    0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 5, 2.333333333, 0, 0, 3, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 1.666666667, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 3.333333333, 
    3, 1.5, 2.2, 0, 0, 1.75, 1.25, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.75, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    0, 8, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2.5, 3, 8, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 8, 9, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    1.75, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1.5, 2, 2, 3, 
    20, 2.5, 2), Area = c(0.032426, 0.035282, 0.113383, 0.035693, 
    0.041549, 0.058353, 0.031573, 0.057897, 0.034298, 0.075203, 
    0.038044, 0.039534, 0.035463, 0.056159, 0.0319, 0.152971, 
    0.063424, 0.033137, 0.184546, 0.054271, 0.043699, 0.070929, 
    0.086888, 0.182135, 0.055882, 0.063176, 0.072119, 0.1096, 
    0.035482, 0.040162, 0.056385, 0.042962, 0.032754, 0.062732, 
    0.056648, 0.035606, 0.062001, 0.117763, 0.062311, 0.089266, 
    0.078665, 0.091633, 0.065517, 0.037454, 0.060411, 0.073355, 
    0.035344, 0.033497, 0.119351, 0.044972, 0.031568, 0.114325, 
    0.068984, 0.061986, 0.109741, 0.033782, 0.031849, 0.105872, 
    0.055202, 0.031857, 0.064647, 0.031718, 0.032588, 0.076284, 
    0.036021, 0.216575, 0.100172, 0.06227, 0.060081, 0.063876, 
    0.224969, 0.045917, 0.037024, 0.077219, 0.054039, 0.158028, 
    0.067884, 0.034719, 0.120346, 0.044812, 0.080923, 0.171879, 
    0.069136, 0.0417, 0.032867, 0.11509, 0.053077, 0.062925, 
    0.033554, 0.07492, 0.114556, 0.096677, 0.049153, 0.161404, 
    0.073527, 0.045258, 0.08603, 0.091654, 0.033591, 0.033243, 
    0.060307, 0.048489, 0.041845, 0.031375, 0.046293, 0.034473, 
    0.044909, 0.052535, 0.060832, 0.082261, 0.086662, 0.031981, 
    0.053075, 0.057269, 0.031764, 0.039376, 0.061771, 0.051374, 
    0.081914, 0.04886, 0.040433, 0.056631, 0.086457, 0.118001, 
    0.033169, 0.033734, 0.064399, 0.065725, 0.043722, 0.062459, 
    0.032385, 0.07605, 0.055818, 0.067326, 0.034017, 0.033867, 
    0.052257, 0.062541, 0.073173, 0.069685, 0.034166, 0.096639, 
    0.081452, 0.116512, 0.064753, 0.12308, 0.033466, 0.050626, 
    0.068697, 0.105123, 0.066668, 0.075515, 0.076373, 0.046068, 
    0.032637, 0.067892, 0.059513, 0.032345, 0.076412, 0.055942, 
    0.057757, 0.070641, 0.038058, 0.04051, 0.049283, 0.063954, 
    0.040222, 0.043146, 0.062292, 0.05944, 0.032226, 0.121329, 
    0.086029, 0.040616, 0.033843, 0.037219, 0.066294, 0.034378, 
    0.117405, 0.095093, 0.032398, 0.062489, 0.060033, 0.0006219274, 
    0.0004771933187, 0.0005009547997, 0.0004406716919, 0.0005174510498, 
    0.0004356966248, 0.0006026420288, 0.0004355072708, 0.0005670226318, 
    0.0004853354187, 0.0005070045624, 0.0005619193115, 0.0006754835205, 
    0.0004834161072, 0.0004468427429, 0.000439496521, 0.0006436887817, 
    0.0006849831238, 0.0005693302002, 0.0004349030151, 0.0004349030151, 
    0.0005387456665, 0.0004572155151, 0.0005252477493, 0.0005314183146, 
    0.0005879613037, 0.0005381040955, 0.0005002150269, 0.0005234927775, 
    0.000592482015, 0.0005348047689, 0.0005223570905, 0.0005260328979, 
    0.0005637895386, 0.0005767995911, 0.000629678894, 0.0005354559326, 
    0.0005431971436, 0.0005328845113, 0.0005311777954, 0.0005214696045, 
    0.0006679819946, 0.0006827795207, 0.0006529239502, 0.0005282859904, 
    0.0005745828705, 0.0005196272583, 0.0006795158081, 0.0005336247467, 
    0.0005789768311, 0.0005680122375), Distance_main = c(1.131059754, 
    0.9597414435, 0, 1.256349606, 1.078548275, 1.855321885, 4.111540893, 
    5.445573732, 4.717162654, 3.192720443, 1.230485339, 4.582202671, 
    2.234386271, 4.464622586, 1.793303323, 3.049223638, 2.517519578, 
    2.538484406, 0.2589592261, 0.8107408556, 1.265087883, 2.583951508, 
    0.5704173619, 0.150727288, 0, 2.880491806, 0.4688362577, 
    1.032252927, 1.711598417, 2.621504704, 0.5018857525, 0.9121811232, 
    1.467942423, 0.5364545556, 1.956558175, 1.903428792, 1.556986206, 
    0.3888441615, 0.2643162488, 0.06508233719, 1.137, 1.050285586, 
    1.40077366, 3.600281886, 2.354502437, 1.899786116, 3.690234235, 
    2.808763349, 0.7511081312, 1.271708613, 2.662284706, 2.675257642, 
    3.518963652, 3.64493179, 2.047243432, 2.681735548, 3.55460067, 
    4.471868465, 4.870529144, 4.073487063, 3.088843029, 4.176214051, 
    3.878882256, 3.798820098, 3.638531617, 3.78621757, 3.517110032, 
    3.885770398, 3.298820012, 3.207448044, 3.236561986, 4.13860818, 
    5.461401614, 3.068585968, 2.839888067, 2.545155836, 2.390539028, 
    3.996152667, 2.813447134, 2.336287582, 3.609633571, 1.994576758, 
    2.756891326, 2.963835872, 2.077835347, 1.981514275, 1.698439482, 
    4.559660757, 1.832220975, 1.538482109, 0.4012068882, 1.011597874, 
    0.2762621903, 0.6604082443, 1.726855522, 0.4426442882, 1.389697061, 
    2.265330127, 4.673539548, 2.833166846, 3.247307991, 1.550221184, 
    1.913466888, 1.02140226, 1.419304966, 4.649917894, 3.021104929, 
    1.138684662, 0.9702250537, 0.8674368023, 1.363686091, 2.237998135, 
    3.078402963, 2.612860775, 2.659002418, 0.7922293863, 0.5605036917, 
    2.918464369, 2.607222198, 2.72011864, 3.293449501, 0.2339249027, 
    0.09269339846, 0.4948047539, 0.988393193, 3.35986433, 3.283307665, 
    0.4664049454, 3.579501178, 0.9978282525, 2.513329669, 1.751686648, 
    2.364558742, 0.3028119337, 0.2667488345, 0.5316889235, 4.034444068, 
    3.413510363, 0.5591667383, 3.303219295, 1.845610995, 2.029920015, 
    1.968676774, 1.642599316, 2.259782135, 1.840349328, 2.169684459, 
    1.466603062, 1.35662262, 1.287059026, 1.114386511, 0.1013909283, 
    0.5191928737, 2.069483497, 2.864063592, 3.741153421, 3.675316052, 
    2.612341652, 2.535722998, 4.374650663, 0.9801658265, 4.516729836, 
    4.200885496, 3.757806231, 2.911160806, 0.08124990183, 4.160713125, 
    4.82011578, 3.805524153, 2.356340037, 2.528406371, 2.849670115, 
    4.335904978, 2.334369917, 1.682493793, 0.9721257977, 2.886626751, 
    1.678288529, 3.207466146, 2.493581595, 1.024302173, 0.2878921523, 
    1.951664026, 0.001168478, 1.9688079e-05, 0.000181543742, 
    0.000169602217, 0.000342252497, 3.8581815e-05, 0.000831689834, 
    0, 0.000310111829, 0.000123848133, 0.00027892549, 0.000474703505, 
    0.000605096677, 0.001312503032, 0.000397102961, 0.001565818974, 
    0.001649622681, 0.0018610356, 0.001417062691, 0.000275126286, 
    0.000431104276, 0.003826022716, 8.0019175e-05, 0.004124439051, 
    0.004485276435, 0.004514712379, 0.00294698083, 0.001935731554, 
    0.002986659776, 0.002716345238, 0.002434957234, 0.002476156054, 
    0.001893628041, 0.001454772675, 0.00099942015, 0.001028825627, 
    0.001531671726, 0.001566268214, 0.001890167805, 0.000937548652, 
    0.000653203203, 0.000456625581, 0.001139386805, 0.001135244462, 
    0, 0.001190210739, 0.000552443287, 0.002855486907, 0.001430594014, 
    0.000594097595, 0.000339933191)), row.names = c(NA, -234L
), class = "data.frame")

mydata = transform(Clean_winter_diff, Site=Site-1)

#separating training and test data
alpha<-0.7
inTrain_diff   <- sample(1:nrow(mydata), alpha * nrow(mydata))
train.set.diff <- mydata[inTrain_diff,]
test.set.diff  <- mydata[-inTrain_diff,]
winter.boost=gbm(Site~. ,data = mydata,n.trees = 10000,
                 shrinkage = 0.01, interaction.depth = 6, cv.folds = 5, verbose = F)

best.iter=gbm.perf(winter.boost, method = "cv")
best.iter
summary(winter.boost)


#Using caret to get model performance in best iteration
set.seed(123)
fitControl = trainControl(method="cv", number=5, returnResamp = "all")

model2 = train(Site~., data=mydata[complete.cases(mydata),], method="gbm",distribution="bernoulli", trControl=fitControl, verbose=F, tuneGrid=data.frame(.n.trees=best.iter, .shrinkage=0.01, .interaction.depth=1, .n.minobsinnode=1))
```

And this are the errors I get:

```
      RMSE        Rsquared        MAE     
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures
```

I have checked the dataframe for missing values, there are none. What is the problem?

`sessionInfo()`:

```
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252  LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252    LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                             LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] caret_6.0-86        ggplot2_3.3.2       lattice_0.20-38     mlbench_2.1-1       gbm_2.1.8           MASS_7.3-51.4       randomForest_4.6-14
 [8] tree_1.0-40         ISLR_1.2            dplyr_1.0.0         rpart.plot_3.0.8    rpart_4.1-15       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tinytex_0.24         tidyselect_1.1.0     xfun_0.15            purrr_0.3.4          reshape2_1.4.4       splines_3.6.2       
 [7] colorspace_1.4-1     vctrs_0.3.1          generics_0.0.2       stats4_3.6.2         survival_3.1-8       prodlim_2019.11.13  
[13] rlang_0.4.7          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 pillar_1.4.6         glue_1.4.1           withr_2.2.0          foreach_1.5.0       
[19] lifecycle_0.2.0      plyr_1.8.6           lava_1.6.7           stringr_1.4.0        timeDate_3043.102    munsell_0.5.0       
[25] gtable_0.3.0         recipes_0.1.13       codetools_0.2-16     parallel_3.6.2       class_7.3-15         Rcpp_1.0.5          
[31] scales_1.1.1         ipred_0.9-9          stringi_1.4.6        grid_3.6.2           tools_3.6.2          magrittr_1.5        
[37] tibble_3.0.3         crayon_1.3.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3      ellipsis_0.3.1       Matrix_1.2-18        data.table_1.13.0   
[43] pROC_1.16.2          lubridate_1.7.9      gower_0.2.2          rstudioapi_0.11      iterators_1.0.12     R6_2.4.1            
[49] nnet_7.3-12          nlme_3.1-142         compiler_3.6.2      
>
```

Comment: Please provide an easily reproducible version of the above code. Most of the packages that are loaded are not required, and when I did run it I get the following error: `The data set is too small or the subsampling rate is too large`.

Comment: since you are using gbm, you can just make Site a factor, ```mydata$Site = factor(mydata$Site)```

Comment: in the example you have provided, the sample size is too small, resulting in the error @RobertWilson pointed to.. can you try using a factor and rerun your caret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a classification, so you need to set the dependent variable to a factor for `train` in `caret` to work:

```
set.seed(123)
fitControl = trainControl(method="cv", number=5, returnResamp = "all")

mydata$Site = factor(mydata$Site)

model2 = train(Site~., data=mydata[complete.cases(mydata),], method="gbm",distribution="bernoulli", trControl=fitControl, verbose=F, tuneGrid=data.frame(.n.trees=400, .shrinkage=0.01, .interaction.depth=1, .n.minobsinnode=1)) 

model2

Stochastic Gradient Boosting 

234 samples
  9 predictor
  2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 187, 187, 187, 188, 187 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.9232192  0.5550649

Tuning parameter 'n.trees' was held constant at a value

Tuning parameter 'n.minobsinnode' was held constant at
 a value of 1
```